# How to change a website to no longer needing an SSL certificate

Tags: ssl-certificate

I have recently had an active website that was protected by an SSL certificate. The site is no longer active and the certificate has expired. I have tried to put up a simple HTML holding page but Google will not show it because there is an expired certificate associated with the domain. Is there a solution to allow me to display the page without needing a certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention what web server or hosting platform you are using. In general yes you can remove an SSL certificate (and stop listening on port 443). But bear in mind if the user has saved a bookmark starting HTTPS, or the links to the site are HTTPS, or if you used the HSTS header to indicate the site should always be viewed over HTTPS then visitors will have trouble viewing the page only accessible over HTTP.

Given you can get a certificate from LetsEncrypt at no cost the most straightforward, and visitor friendly, option would be to renew the certificate.